# How to handle in memory data with multiple threads and persistence in Java

Tags: java, database, nosql, persistence

I have a Java webapp (running on Tomcat or Jetty) which is only used by a few concurrent users (3-5). The data is managed by Hibernate on an HSQLDB, in memory. The DB is flushed to disk automatically.

The amount of data is not that big, and the performed SQL queries are not so special (mostly direct retrieval by primary key).

I have the feeling Hibernate and SQL are a massive overhead for what I am actually doing.

All I need is a datamodel to be available for all threads, making sure that changes in the model can be transactional. If needed, I don't even mind locking the full data model per transaction! Also, the model should be serialized to disk on a regular basis to avoid data loss in case of a crash.

Is there anything out there which can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could cache them, either using something like EhCache, or having a common set of Maps keyed by the ID.  Maps are incredibly fast for lookups.  You would have to synchronize them, either by using synchronized blocks or by using a synchronized collection, to ensure you don't read and write to the collection at the same time.  The thing to look out for is ConcurrentModificationException, which happens when you are iterating over a collection (like in a foreach loop) and some other thread changes the underlying collection.

Comment: @CodeChimp: Maps are great if the data doesn't need to persist from one application restart to another. If this is the case, using ConcurrentMap eliminates CocnurrentModificationException. But OP is looking for a more persistent way of managing data.

Comment: exact. The maps sounds good, and I could use synchronized, but I still need the persistence, and not to forget the transactions

Comment: I think EhCache would be a good option, then.  I believe it has the ability to persist the cache.  There may be other caching offerings, like more commercial ones, but I haven't had to use anything other than EhCache.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the database.  You're going to drive yourself up the wall if you try to re-invent a DB on your own.

At best, you might want to look into NoSQL databases.  These can be simpler than SQL databases.

Comment: I had a look at some NoSQL databases, but most run on a separate server. I dont have that today (HSQLDB runs embedded) and dont want to introduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that Hibernate is a massive overhead, consider using straight JDBC. Although, if SQL is the percieved problem and your data model is very simple, you might be better off with Hibernate instead of the JDBC.

Comment: The question is not really about the choice between Hibernate and JDBC. It is more about moving away from a SQL database. I want to keep my model in memory, approach it in a clean way, and be able to persist it.

Comment: As soon as you introduce requirements for persistence and for support of multiple classes/entity types, I can only second the @Mark Robinson advice: do not try to re-invent a DB on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Sqlite... You get all from HSQL and plus you have persistence.
No Database manager needed. Nothing is required to be installed.

Comment: I dont get it. SQLite and HSQLDB are just alternatives of each other, no? SQLite still binds me to SQL usage.

Comment: SQLite is like HSQLDB, but data is persisted to database file. Yes you are stil bound to implicit SQL usage with SQLite. And, don't think that SQL and Hibernate are bottlnecks of your project, that is very unlikely.